# Finding a combination of characters and digits in a string python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of lists, and I'm attempting to loop through and check to see if the strings in a specific index in each of the inner lists contain a combination of "XY" and then 4 numbers immediately following. The "XY" could be in various locations of the string, so I'm struggling with the syntax beyond just using "XY" in row[5]. How to I add the digits after the "XY" to check? Something that combines the "XY" and isdigit()? Am I stuck using the find function to return an index and then going from there?

Comment: a specific input and expected output format would help.

Comment: You can do the whole thing in a fairly straightforward way, without having to iterate multiple times. Please include a sample of the data in your question (appropriately formatted) and share some of the code you've tried so far, so people can tell you made an effort but also (more importantly) to show where you're stuck and from what point onwards you need help. Depending on what you want to do with the found items, one way or another to find them may be better - please also specify what you need the found items for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's regex module `re` with this pattern that matches `XY` and then four digits anywhere in the string.

```
import re
pattern = r'XY\d{4}'

my_list = [['XY0'],['XY1234','AB1234'],['XY1234','ABC123XY5678DEF6789']]

elem_to_check = 1
for row in my_list:
    if len(row) > elem_to_check: 
        for found in re.findall(pattern, row[elem_to_check]):
            print(f'{found} found in {row[elem_to_check]}')
```

Output:

```
XY5678 found in ABC123XY5678DEF6789
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that out, I'm not familiar with that module but looks helpful